# Parsing JSON array in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to get the hand on JQuery and JSON using an ASP.NET webservice. The Webservice returns this result:

```
{
    MyResult: {
        Ticket: {
            "Author": "rd",
            "CssClass": "RED",
            "ExpirationDateTime": "2009-08-16T16:55:43.577+02:00",
            "id": "38",
            "Message": "We are going down",
            "ModifiedDateTime": "2009-08-17T11:14:20.5+02:00",
            "MoreInfo": null 
        } 
    }
}
```

On the client side I'm using JQuery to get the result using the ajax function like this:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "TickerFeeder.asmx/GetTicket",
   data: "{}",
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   dataType: "json",
   success: function(resultJSON) {
     //-- Please fill your code here for getting the first item from the array into variables
   }
```

But I'm missing out the stuff how to retrieve the first item from the JSON array into some variables. Something like this (pseudo-code):

```
var message = resultJSON[0].Message
var cssclass = resultJSON[0].CssClass
```

Anybody with a hint,help?

Thanks for your help
Cheers
Frank

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your JSON is [not valid](http://www.jsonlint.com/), you should use quotes on the `MyResult` and `Ticket` members.

```
{
    "MyResult": {
        "Ticket": {
            "Author": "rd",
            "CssClass": "RED",
            "ExpirationDateTime": "2009-08-16T16:55:43.577+02:00",
            "id": "38",
            "Message": "We are going down",
            "ModifiedDateTime": "2009-08-17T11:14:20.5+02:00",
            "MoreInfo": null 
        } 
    }
}
```

Also there is no array involved, the arrays are defined with the square bracket characters `[....]` [literal notation](http://json.org/array.gif), so you can access your values directly:

```
resultJSON.MyResult.Ticket.Message;
resultJSON.MyResult.Ticket.CssClass;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found out that my Asp.Net webService was producing a wrong result set. So instead of returning a string item I returned a complete object and handled the Json conversion to Asp.Net webservice. That did the trick !